# Odd MySQL Date Behavior

Tags: mysql

MySQL seems to not be able to convert certain times. Any thoughts on why this happens would be hugely appreciated.

Examples:

These times work fine...

```
select STR_TO_DATE('2022-07-11 6:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
2022-07-11 6:00:00

select STR_TO_DATE('2022-07-11 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
2022-07-11 10:00:00
```

But, 8am or 9am will show 0:00 for the time...

```
select STR_TO_DATE('2022-07-11 8:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
2022-07-11 0:00:00

select STR_TO_DATE('2022-07-11 9:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
2022-07-11 0:00:00
```

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3y5wvb6b7 works just fine

Comment: Always investigate the function description before you use it !!! `%H` is a pattern which matches "hours, 00..23", i.e. with leading zeros. If your value to be converted contains the hours value without leading zeros you myst use the pattern `%k`.

Comment: @IłyaBursov This is MySQL version-dependent.

Comment: @Akina Notice in my example that the same formatting works with other non-leading zero value of 6am. %k is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Had nothing to do with value formatting. The problem turned out to be a bug with the MySQL client on a PC.

When using the MySQL client on a Mac, it worked with out issue:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('2022-07-11 8:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
2022-07-11 08:00:00
```